# Narrow object keys based on function parameter value

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it with the newest version of typescript possible to narrow the properties of an object based on **values** supplied via parameters without specifying them as separate generic type for the function?

I would like the following to work in which the function signature of `bar` returns an object with the keys supplied as parameter.
Theoretically if the parameters are constant it should be possible to infer the signature.

```js
interface ModelType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  timestamp: Date;
}


class Foo<T, K extends keyof T  = keyof T>{
  public bar(selectedField : K[]) : Pick<T,K>{
    return {} as any;
  }
}

const foobar = new Foo<ModelType>().bar(['id','name']);

console.log(foobar.id)          //Success
console.log(foobar.name)        //Success
console.log(foobar.timestamp)   //Should be an error
```

I tried any kind of combination with `typeof selectedValues` unarray but just end up with the full set of K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Class method [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

You can add generic types to the class method to `extends` the `generic type` of the class as follow:

```
class Foo<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T>{
  // using generic types in your class method
  public bar<L extends K>(selectedField : L[]) : Pick<T,L>{
    return {} as any;
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2AVATwAcUBvAKGWWEwC5kBnMKUAcwG5LkQ4BbCekxYgOXMMH5M+RegBE4kTgF9yqhDjgMGyAGLp0AHjwAaZAGlkEAB6QQmbQGsIBdDGR5kAXmROXbvAB8FFQA9CHIAK4MbMisECDQwAjIYMQQ2qDILhFQyOqa2vxgABZYXEQRAEY4SciVcFAGADKWNvH25gEAFAy4EAiQmDrAuJjI9E0A2gC6AJTjyAAKSQ5Gxk1BXFRQEGA5IMikSsiaJyAEnFQqKuQI6CBMyDD69bneCQDuuvoGGNj4aW6swAdK8upMAOQ0CHGCE8fgQuacW73BjoHAQYE4dCsLrPdCvYE0eZUUlksIAZQiCCQWhRD3RmOxuPxhPhEBJZNCISpNPSDHpaIxWJxeJeDWB4kkYGknMppQiODGlRQcAO0Cg6CgQA)